# Does @ControllerAdvice override SimpleMappingExceptionResolver?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, exception

I have `SimpleMappingExceptionResolver` configured like so.

```
@Bean(name = "simpleMappingExceptionResolver")
public SimpleMappingExceptionResolver createSimpleMappingExceptionResolver() {
    SimpleMappingExceptionResolver r = new SimpleMappingExceptionResolver();

    Properties mappings = new Properties();
    mappings.setProperty("InvalidRequestException", "error");
    mappings.setProperty("GenericServerException", "error");
    mappings.setProperty("IllegalArgumentException", "error");

    r.setExceptionMappings(mappings);
    r.setDefaultErrorView("error");
    r.setExceptionAttribute(DEFAULT_EXCEPTION_ATTRIBUTE);
    r.setWarnLogCategory("org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleMappingExceptionResolver");
    return r;
}
```

But I have a `@ControllerAdvice` defined for `MethodArgumentNotValidException.class` and placed within `@ComponentScan` reach. But for some reason my `@ExceptionHandler` annotated method in `@ControllerAdvice` class is not called. I do see a stacktrace however. It prompts me to think, spring is using some defaultHandler for `MethodArgumentNotValidException.class`.

```
WARN : org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleMappingExceptionResolver - Handler execution resulted in exception
org.springframework.web.bind.MethodArgumentNotValidException: Validation failed for argument at index 0 in method: public com.mrll.global.profile.model.PasswordInfo com.mrll.global.controller.PasswordController.passwordInfo(com.mrll.global.core.password.PasswordChange) throws com.mrll.global.profile.PasswordChangeException, with 1 error(s): [Field error in object 'passwordChange' on field 'oldPassword': rejected value []; codes [NotEmpty.passwordChange.oldPassword,NotEmpty.oldPassword,NotEmpty.java.lang.String,NotEmpty]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [passwordChange.oldPassword,oldPassword]; arguments []; default message [oldPassword]]; default message [may not be empty]] 
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.validate(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:119)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:101)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:77)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:157)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:124)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:953)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:855)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:829)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.__invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:879)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:600)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:1703)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
DEBUG: com.mrll.utility.Constants - end ConstantsReloader
```

Why doen't the ControllerAdvice get called ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As explained by [this](http://java.dzone.com/articles/using-springs) blog post Spring can only load one `HandlerExceptionResolver`.

That means that when you specify an implementation of it as a bean (which is exactly what you are doing with `SimpleMappingExceptionResolver`) then Spring will not use the it's default implementation (which up until before Spring 3.2 was `AnnotationMethodHandlerExceptionResolver` - since Spring 3.2 the default implementation used by Spring is `ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver`).

The default implementation that is used by Spring is the one that uses `@ExceptionHandler` in order to handle exceptions that is why that approach works out of the box.

A possible work around that you could explore if you want to use both strategies, is to use `HandlerExceptionResolverComposite` as described in [this](http://doanduyhai.wordpress.com/2012/05/06/spring-mvc-part-v-exception-handling/) blog post